# Where might the code for this screenshot lie in joomla 4

Tags: joomla-4.x, joomla-4

The link to this url on localhost is `administrator/index.php?option=com_menus&view=item&client_id=0&layout=edit&id=101`

[image]

Comment: There will be multiple scripts contributing to that display.  Your question is Too Broad.  Please tell us about the specific/narrow issue that you are experiencing so that we can understand what you actually need help with.  Show us what you've tried and tell us what you understand already so that we don't tell you what you already know.  Your question is not currently a good fit for this community because it is unlikely to attract clear, concise answers that will benefit future researchers.  Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

The view is created from the code in ..\administrator\components\com_menus\views\item\tmpl starting with edit.php and your particular tab would be edit_modules.php

I got there by decoding your URL, **administrator**/index.php?option=**com**_**menus**&view=**item**&client_id=0&layout=**edit**&id=101 and knowing it would be under /components and /tmpl

It does use code from the ..\item directory above it and other places but as posted by @mickmackusa unless you provide more context in the question I cannot be sure if this is enough information for you or if you already knew this.

Comment: @TirelessWorker if this answer was helpful to you I would appreciate it if you would accept the answer so that it at least shows your issue has been resolved and no further action is likely. It is not compulsory to accept an answer, https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers, but it does help encourage people like me to take the time to answer more questions for you and other people.

Comment: That's a good starting point, but I think a specific problem is needed to be sure it's the right answer.  But top marks for explaining how you knew where to look.